# PowerShell: ConvertTo-Csv and then Set-Content by object filter

Tags: powershell

I have the following variables:

```
$input = "H:\input_file.txt"
$output = "H:\output_file.txt"
$data = Get-Content -Path $input | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Header 'Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5'
```

As seen above, the input file has 5 columns.  This file has various record types in it.  Not all record types have 5 columns defined.  So, let's say I have 3 record types -- A, B, and C.  A has 3 columns, B has 4 columns, and C has 5 columns.  An example input file looks like:

```
A|x|1
B|y|2|stuff
C|z|3|stuff|other
B|y|3|other
A|z|2
```

My script then makes some modifications to the values in some of the columns (except for Col1) in $data.  I want to output all rows in $data to a text file.

If I do something like

```
$data | Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path $output
```

it will append unnecessary pipe characters to record types A and B (because they have less than 5 columns, and yet I am doing `Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5`).

Is there a clean way to output $data to a text file without the unnecessary pipe characters on record types A and B?  My best guess at the moment is to have 3 separate pipelines for record types A, B, and C, such that I am doing the correct Select for the given record type, and then gluing them all together somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The following code might be useful for you:

```
@"
A|x|1||
B|y|2|stuff|
C|z|3|stuff|other
B|y|3|other|
A|z|2||
"@ -split '\r\n' | % { $_ -replace '\|+$', '' }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems little tricky and better to do some string manipulations I feel,

```
$data|ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation|ForEach-Object{$_.replace('","','|').replace('"','').replace(',','')}|Select-Object -Skip 1|Set-Content $outputtext
```

here by avoiding _delimiter , we canmake use of some string handling methods in PowerShell

Regards,
Prasoon Karunan V